# How to remove title bar on xamarin wpf and make the application full screen

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin, desktop-application

How to remove title bar on xamarin wpf and make the application full screen?

Behavior of xamarin wpf full screen is different from original wpf application.
When i enable the full screen mode by

`ResizeMode="NoResize",
 WindowState="Normal",
 WindowStyle="None",
 Topmost="True",
 WindowState = "Maximized";`

The application is not actually remove the titlebar and hide the taskbar.

Is there any way to achieve same behavior as native WPF application ?

[image: sample below]

Comment: Probably `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"` will help you

Comment: @JoãoFernandes no, not working.

Comment: just a thought, but in your question you have WindowState= Normal and WindowState=Maximized but have you put it in as a borderless form?

Answer (score 3):

That's how I removed all the bars create by Xamarin.Forms (tested in v3.2):

1. In WPF native project go to MainWindow.xaml.cs
2. Add the remove method:

   > ```
   >   private bool topBarsRemoved = false;
   >
   >   private void RemoveTopBars()
   >   {
   >       System.Windows.Controls.Grid commandBar = this.Template.FindName("PART_CommandsBar", this) as System.Windows.Controls.Grid;
   >
   >       if (commandBar != null)
   >           (commandBar.Parent as System.Windows.Controls.Grid)?.Children.Remove(commandBar);
   >
   >       var topAppBar = this.Template.FindName("PART_TopAppBar", this) as WpfLightToolkit.Controls.LightAppBar;
   >       if (topAppBar != null)
   >         (topAppBar.Parent as System.Windows.Controls.Grid)?.Children.Remove(topAppBar);
   >
   >       topBarsRemoved = true;
   >   }
   > ```
3. Call the method:

> ```
> protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
> {
>   base.OnActivated(e);    
>   if (!topBarsRemoved) RemoveTopBars();
> }
> ```